# TIBCO BW 6 advancement date

Tags: tibco, tibco-business-works

in TIBCO BW 6.5.1, how do you advance a date by x days?
I would need a solution that advances where the year and month are needed.
Example: The current date advanced by 90 days.
current date 2024-01-09 + 90 days = 2024-04-08
(I hope I did the calculation right :) )
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

you can try use **add-to-date()** function it will look like this:

```
tib:add-to-date(current-date(),0,0,90)
```

Comment: Hello Ariclene, thank you for your answer.
I will try to solve my problem using this function.